# bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or director

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04.1 following the instructions. But met a problem, details like below:

```
bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Then i check the directory of "/opt", found that it is empty, like below:

```
ros@ubuntu:/opt$ ls -al

total 8

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 21 13:40 .

drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Dec 21 13:35 ..

ros@ubuntu:/opt$
```

And when i executed the commands(like following), it gave the same error.

```
echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199893/bash:-/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-director/) by [fireice](https://answers.ros.org/users/21193/fireice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-22**:
Did anything fail during `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-destop-full` ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-22**:
Also: which "instructions"?

**Comment by [fireice](https://answers.ros.org/users/21193/fireice/) on 2014-12-22**:
@Wolf  I used `sudo apptitude install ros-indigo-desktop-full` instead of `sudo apt-get`.

But there were no error.

**Comment by [fireice](https://answers.ros.org/users/21193/fireice/) on 2014-12-22**:
@gvdhoorn following this one: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [krishna890227](https://answers.ros.org/users/27376/krishna890227/) on 2016-07-04**:
Hi friends
I am also suffering from same problems in my raspberryPI 3B. My operating system is NOOBS, but i found command line instruction for Wheezy or Jessie.  How can i solve these problems.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-04**:
@krishna890227 please open a new question, with sufficient info of your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You simply didn't install anything.
Since you are going to use Ubuntu 14.04.1 it is for you the best option to simply install from the repository.
[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) you have the procedure. Just pay attention to every code of line, don't forget any instructions. Later on you can [configure](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) your environment accordingly. The first 2-3 times I had problems too. The first problem to understand,why and what you need to run ROS. But after that you can fast realize that's quite normal and it won't be  a problem anymore :P

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fireice](https://answers.ros.org/users/21193/fireice/) on 2014-12-22**:
thanks! i will try again.